# Почему Tkinter не читает значения из переменной?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть телеграм-бот, который читает широту и долготу из чата, есть tkintermapview, которая отображает карту и есть файл, в котором находятся две переменные, которые бот меняет. Бот исправно вседелает. Но почему-то tkinter при чтении этих переменных выдает 0.0. В чем моя ошибка? Вроде бы и к нужному float типу привожу.

Бот

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

import values


api_id = '00000000'
api_hash = '000000000000000000000000000000000000'
bot_token = '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
telegram_group_id = -10000000000


app = Client("my_bot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)


# Обработчик для обновлений сообщений
@app.on_message(filters.chat(telegram_group_id))
def handle_messages(client, message):
    # global latitude, longitude

    try:
        if message.text is not None:
            coordinates_str = message.text.split(';')[-1]
            latitude, longitude = map(float, coordinates_str.split(','))
            values.latitude = float(latitude)
            values.longitude = float(longitude)
            print(values.latitude, values.longitude)
    except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
        print(f"Error processing message: {e}")



app.run()
```

Графический интерфейс

```
import tkinter
import tkintermapview
import values

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry(f"{800}x{600}")
root.title("map_view_example.py")



def start_map():
    create_map()
    root.after(10000, start_map)


map_widget = tkintermapview.TkinterMapView(root, width=800, height=600, corner_radius=0)
map_widget.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
map_widget.set_zoom(15)


def create_map():
    latitude = float(values.latitude)
    longitude = float(values.longitude)
    map_widget.set_position(latitude, longitude)
    marker_1 = map_widget.set_marker(latitude, longitude)
    print(values.latitude, values.longitude)


root.after(1000, start_map)
root.mainloop()
```

Файл values

```
latitude = 0.0
longitude = 0.0
```

Comment: Потому что вы запустили их в двух отдельных процессах, например?

Comment: Объясните, как их можно запустить в одном? Как я только не старался - результата нет. Или бот перестает работать или карта не отображается.

Comment: После импорта `values` - это уже как бы локальная переменная того скрипта, куда вы её импортировали. Ну или, другими словами, `import` работает один раз и в одну сторону. Что вы там меняете в одном скрипте никак не отражается на других скриптах. Пишите данные либо в БД, либо, например, в `json` файл, который будете читать каждый раз в `create_map`.

Comment: Как вариант - использовать [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) и Queue или Pipe для обмена данными между процессами.